# find_element_by_xpath not working in headless mode python

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome

I am using selenium with python and the code below works fine when i run it in non headless mode, but when i switch to headless mode it gives me this error :

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[.='Renee']"}
(Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.82)
```

code :

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 
import sys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import pyperclip
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import warnings


warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)    


browser_locale = 'fr'
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang={}".format(browser_locale))
# for linux/Ubuntu only
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home')
voice = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downshift-2-toggle-button"]/span')
voice.click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='Renee']").click()
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-area"]')
search.clear()
search.send_keys("text here")
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser_locale = 'fr'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang={}".format(browser_locale))
#options.headless = True

options.add_argument("--headless")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get('https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label downshift-0-toggle-button"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@class="bx--list-box__menu-item__option" and contains(text(),"German")]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label downshift-0-toggle-button"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@class="bx--list-box__menu-item__option" and contains(text(),"French")]').click()
voice = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="downshift-2-toggle-button"]/span')
voice.click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='Renee']").click()

search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-area"]')
search.clear()
search.send_keys("text here")
```

Just select the language again to enable the drop down, in headless mode it is showing as disabled , take a screenshot and check

Comment: working like charm, thank you soo much for your time